# android-how to put the text on the image in gridview

Tags: android, android-gridview

In my application, I'm using a gridview to display images, but I want to display the text on the images. Is this possible? If so, how can I implement it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just give you a hint.

You must have seen "hello gridview" here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

You just need to get a custom view (may be a LinearLayout) instead of a imageview in getview() in adapter.

Hope this help.